# 2008 Mac Pro Freezes After Selecting a boot option in Startup Manager

Tags: macos, mac

I have a 2008 Mac Pro that boots to a flashing ? folder icon. I cannot boot into Recovery. I can boot into the Startup Manager by holding the Option key.

In Startup Manager, a configured hard drive with OSX 10.11 installed is available, the Recovery partition of that hard drive, and a separate OSX installer on a USB. When any of these boot options is selected, the computer then freezes on a gray screen.

I've tried the PRAM, NVRAM resets, the SMC reset, switching drive bays, etc. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue.  Try [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: The 08 doesn’t have AHT built-in but there is a downloadable version you can boot from a USB stick. I’m on my phone for the week which makes searching through AD difficult, but I have in the past posted a link to it in one of my own answers.